# jquery.ajax calling a .aspx web method

Tags: jquery, asp.net, ajax, webmethod

I had the below code working in a POC without variables and hard coded everything. After introducing variables to prepare for using this channel it stopped working. Likely, there is a syntax error I am not seeing, or (I don't dare say) this POC is not able to support such requests?

**from my aspx page sendEmail.aspx**

```
     [System.Web.Services.WebMethod]
                public static string SendMyEmail(string EmailFromAddress, string EmailFromName, string EmailSubject, string EmailBody)
                {

                    return "data from server: " + Environment.NewLine +
                            "EmailFromAddress = " + EmailFromAddress + Environment.NewLine +
                            "from = " + EmailFromName + Environment.NewLine +
                            "from = " + EmailSubject + Environment.NewLine +
                            "from = " + EmailBody;

                }

    <script type = "text/javascript">
    function ShowCurrentTime() {
        alert("hi");

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "SendEmail.aspx/SendMyEmail",
            data: '{EmailFromAddress: "mike", EmailFromName="mike", EmailSubject="email subject here", EmailBody="email body here"}',
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",
            success: OnSuccess,
            failure: function (response) {
                alert(response.d);
            }
        });
    }
```

**from my html web page:**

```
<script type = "text/javascript">
function ShowCurrentTime() {
    alert("hi");

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "SendEmail.aspx/SendMyEmail",
        data: '{EmailFromAddress: "mike", EmailFromName="mike", EmailSubject="email subject here", EmailBody="email body here"}',
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        success: OnSuccess,
        failure: function (response) {
            alert(response.d);
        }
    });
}

function OnSuccess(response) {
    alert("all good");

    alert(response.d);
}
</script> 
</head>
<body style = "font-family:Arial; font-size:10pt">
<form id="form1" runat="server">
<div>
Your Name : 
<asp:TextBox ID="txtUserName" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
<input id="btnGetTime" type="button" value="Show Current Time" 
    onclick = "ShowCurrentTime()" />
</div>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

It works well when the web method has one pram (like below) even with multiple data points in the json data:

```
[System.Web.Services.WebMethod]
        public static string SendMyEmail(string EmailFromAddress)
        {

            return "good data from server: " + EmailFromAddress;

        }
```

Comment: try passing in all variables that the webmethod needs.  you are just sending EmailFromAddress, try adding the rest.  Most likely passing in just that 1 parameter the system is looking for a method with just that param.

Comment: no-go, I originally had it as: data: '{EmailFromAddress: "mike", EmailFromName="mike", EmailSubject="email subject here", EmailBody="email body here"}',

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your ajax should look like this.  Remove the '=' and replace with ':' to create proper json in the data field.

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "SendEmail.aspx/SendMyEmail",
    data: '{EmailFromAddress: "mike", EmailFromName: "mike", EmailSubject: "email subject here", EmailBody: "email body here"}',
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    dataType: "json",
    success: OnSuccess,
    failure: function (response) {
        alert(response.d);
    }
});
```